# dependent-name T is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I realize that there have been some questions on SO touching this subject but I haven't found the solution yet.

I would like to enable function `f` only when all of its arguments are pod.

I have the following piece of code to do this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Conds>
struct and_ : std::true_type
{
};

template <typename Cond, typename... Conds>
struct and_<Cond, Conds...> :
    std::conditional<Cond::value, and_<Conds...>, std::false_type>::type
{
};

template <typename... T>
using are_all_pod = and_<std::is_pod<T>...>;

template<typename... Args,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<are_all_pod<Args...>::type>>
void f(Args ... args)
{
}

int main()
{
  f(1,2);
}
```

I do receive the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:25:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(int, int)’
   f(1,2);
        ^
main.cpp:19:6: note: candidate: template<class ... Args, class> void f(Args ...)
 void f(Args ... args)
      ^
main.cpp:19:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:18:10: error: dependent-name ‘and_<std::is_pod<T>...>::type’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
          typename = typename std::enable_if<are_all_pod<Args...>::type>>
          ^
main.cpp:18:10: note: say ‘typename and_<std::is_pod<T>...>::type’ if a type is meant
```

I tried following compiler's advice but I get the same error then. Using gcc 5.2.1

Comment: "I get the same error then" - exactly the same error?

Comment: So what do you want to do

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit please check my edit

Comment: Better to use `std::enable_if` for the return type, or before the `=`. As currently, you will have issue if you want the disabled part.

Comment: @Jarod42 can you elaborate on "before the `=`? And why would I have issues if I want the disabled part?

Comment: something like `typename std::enable_if<..>::type* = nullptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::enable_if<are_all_pod<Args...>::type>` makes no sense.

Change it to something like `std::enable_if<are_all_pod<Args...>::value, void>::type` and the program will compile.